# Question using jQuery "load" method along with a GET request

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to load the results of a get request of an external php file into a div.

Here is the jQuery code that I am using:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#output").load("php/create_rows.php?" + $.param({ "type": "unique", "unit": "day", "interval": 2 }));
  });
</script>
```

Here is the code on my php page:

```
  $type = $_GET['type'];
  $unit = $_GET['unit'];
  $interval = $_GET['interval'];

  echo("The type is: " . $type);
  echo("The unit is: " . $unit);
  echo("The interval is: " . $interval);
```

The console has no errors, so I am sure that the jQuery load is working correctly.

I expected the div with ID output to contain the values of type, unit, and interval that I passed in. Unfortunately, the div with ID output is empty.

I am new to PHP, so maybe I am using echo wrong? I don't know.

Edit 1:

The get parameters are being sent correctly. Here is the output:
The type is: unique
The unit is: day
The interval is: 2
The property is: 
The property_value is: 
000%00%

Inside of my create_rows.php file, I have a require:   require("processData.php");

I put an "echo 'Hello World';" in the processData.php file, but it is not showing up in the console.

Comment: what browser are you using?   if your using firefox, look in the firebug console and see if the request is happening, and what is being returned.  if your using IE,  open up the developer tools (press f12), and then open up the network tab,  and press start capuring,  and then refresh the page,  your request should show up.  let us know what's in the response body.

Comment: Your echo is wrong! remove the brackets, like this: `echo "The type is: " . $type;`

Comment: How can I do this using Google Chrome? I know Chrome has a set of developer tools built-in.

Comment: @Ravan: It should still work with the parenthesis.

Comment: the same as IE, press f12, click the network tab, and then refresh the page, you should see a request for the page, and then another request to your create_rows page

Comment: @egidra Press F12 and see the Network tab.

Comment: @Rocket, You're right. Since echo is a language construct, it was my first clue that it could messed the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the query vars are being set? Can you confirm via firebug that they are being passed? Try using isset() and empty() to verify on the server side they have been set. Also, if echo never turns out what I want I run a var_dump, which will output a lot more details (including data type) and let you know if it is empty or non existent (echo will just output nothing). And your using echo properly.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is 100% correct. I've done a fast simulation with what you provided and I got the response as expected. Only thing I could think of is that the div has "display:none".

As for the second problem try using

```
die("Hello World");
```

instead of:

```
echo "Hello World";
```

to see if the script follows desired execution path.

EDIT:
If I'm reading correctly you're trying to see echoed string in JS console? Not happening.